# How to check if a value was selected from multi select pick list field in custom controller

Tags: apex, custom-controller

I am trying to build custom validation in my custom controller for a VF page. I have a field which is a multi select pick list. I would like to check if 'Other' is part of the list of values selected, and if yes, display an error. This is what I have done so far, based on my research:

```
if (acc.Donor_Interests__c.contains('Other') && acc.Donor_Interests_Other__c == null){
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Please provide details of Donor Interests - Other in the field below.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                return null;
}
```

In this case I get an error "Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Answer (score 3):

You need to first check if it has *any* value, before parsing it to find specific values.

```
if (acc.Donor_Interests__c != null && ...)
```

I would adjust your approach as well though, to actually split on the selection delimiter (`';'`). To explain why, consider if your picklist had two options: `Other` and `Other Option`. If someone selects the latter, your current approach would consider `Other` to be selected, even though it is not. Instead, use the `String.split` method.

```
if (acc.Donor_Interests__c != null)
{
    List<String> selections = acc.Donor_Interests__c.split(';');
    if (selections.contains('Other') && acc.Donor_Interests_Other__c == null)
    {
        // bingo
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With latest Salesforce updates, we can use [safe navigation operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) (?.) now for null check.
Modifying your condition like this should help

```
if (acc.Donor_Interests__c?.contains('Other') && ...)
```

Comment: The Safe Navigation Operator (SNO) won't work in this scenario because when `Donor_Interests__c` is null, the SNO returns null. `if(null && <other things>)` is not valid syntax and I think you'd still end up with a Null Pointer Exception in this case.

Comment: Also, the SNO was introduced in Winter '21 (API v50.0), so I wouldn't really say "latest" here.